# Can I run my own cable wires?

Tags: wiring, cables, internet

I live down a side road that is not supported by my local cable company (they used to, but not enough people used the service to justify the maintenance cost), meaning that I cannot get fast, stable Internet. Is it possible to run my own cables somehow and get the cable company to use them? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not electronic *design*.

Comment: this is primarily a question for your ISP, isn't it? some ISPs will supply internet into any dark fiber, but they might be more in the datacenter business than private connections

Comment: Try talking to their competition: the local fiber cable company, or cellular phone companies that service fixed locations (T-Mobile and Verizon both have "Home Internet" services that connect over the cellular network)

Comment: we, by the way, don't even know where you are. The US-American and German internet market work a bit differently, and I assume the various South American markets, the Indian, the Chinese and the Micronesian might as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more for home improvement stack exchange, but in a word: no. They will probably gladly *take your money* (lots of it) to lay their own cable, all the while making you think they are doing you a big favor by taking your money. They won't be taking responsibility for any cable laid by you.

Especially that it takes a bit of engineering knowledge to know what sort of a cable to lay anyway. The system such a cable ties into has to remain within FCC-mandated RF leakage limits. You'd probably need to buy that cable from a specialist supplier, who may well not even sell to non-businesses, etc. In short: you claim you can do a cable installation contractor's job. That's a bit of a tall tale.

I suggest checking out Starlink. It may just be what you need.